# Как включить поиск с учетом морфологии в PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Используется PostgreSQL версии 8.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно установить словарь русского языка my_spell. На Ubuntu это будет

```
apt-get install myspell-ru
```

и поиск заработает.